# Synchronization of 2 swipers in vue3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Vue 3, composition api, typescript.

In my project there are 2 galleries on swiper, one of which is in a modal window. They are in different components and synchronized. By clicking on the preview, I pass the index like this:

```
const openLightbox = (index: number) => {
  lightbox.value = true;
  slide.value = index;
};



<swiper
      :slides-per-view="1.5"
      @swiper="onSwiper"
    >
      <swiper-slide v-for="(item, index) in reals" :key="item.id" @click="openLightbox(index)">
        <RealsSlide :reals_data="item" />
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
    <teleport to="body">
      <div class="reals-lightbox" v-show="lightbox">
        <div class="reals-lightbox__dialog">
          <button @click="closeLightbox">
            <svg width="14" height="14"><use xlink:href="#close" /></svg>
          </button>
          <RealsCarousel :reals="reals" :current-slide="slide" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </teleport>
```

In the gallery component in the modal window I get index like this:

```
const props = defineProps({   currentSlide: Number });
        
  const { currentSlide } = toRefs(props);
        
  watch(currentSlide, () => {   
    if (swiperRef.value !== null) {
       swiperRef.value.slideTo(props.currentSlide);   
    }});
```

And it works fine if you don't swipe the gallery in the modal window. If you swipe the gallery in the modal window, close the modal window, and then click on the preview again, the last slide from the swipe is displayed, and not the one that corresponds to the index.

console.log shows that the index is passed correctly.

What can cause such a problem with synchronization?

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example of the problem.